# Put div on top of the text

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I have been trying and I don't really know how to solve this:
I need to style the title of the content like this:
Now, I've been trying to have `position:absolute` some other stuff, but it just doesn't seem to work.
[image]

My code:

```
 <div class="content_item">
      <div class="double_line"></div>
      <h2>Ce facem</h2>
 </div>
```

css:

```
.content_item>div{
border-top: 2px solid #c2c1c1;
border-bottom: 2px solid #a5a4a4;
display:inline-block;
width:100%;
height:5px;
position: absolute;
}
.content_item>h2{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

So what I wanted was to put the text over the line and a white background on the text.
fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qu849/

Can you please help me?

Comment: see my edit code. usefull for you  and see this link http://jsfiddle.net/bipin_kumar/35T7S/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fiddle kinda works:
http://jsfiddle.net/Qu849/4/

Anyway I wouldn't do that code for this purpose. Consider this:
Just use a div with a `background image` (repeat-x) with those "borders"

Inside that div use a span, centered, and with a `background:#fff;`

That is just better.

**EDIT**

Check @drip answer to do what I described:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/20070686/2600397

Answer (score 2):

You need to position you h2 above your bordered div. My idea would be to make h2 `display:inline-block;` so you can use `text-align:center;` on the parent to center the child h2 and then just use `position:relative;` and `top:-20px;` on the h2 to move it up a bit

```
.content_item{    
    border-top: 2px solid #c2c1c1;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #a5a4a4;    
    width:100%;
    height:5px;
    position:relative; 
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:50px;   
 }
.content_item > h2{
        text-align: center;
        background-color: white;
        padding:3px 15px;
        font-size:14px;        
        display:inline-block;
        position:relative;
        top:-20px;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Qu849/8/

Answer (score 1):

Since the `double_line` div is absolutely positioned, it will be above any none positioned elements.

to put both elements on a relative plane, you need to position the h2 in the same manner (either absolute, or relative).

After that you can play with the margins or top/left properties of the elements to position them over each other.

Comment: The problem is that I will not be able to do it this way since it will need to work for every content title, and it will be hard if it depends on the content, because the content is so diverse (images, text, video, etc)

Comment: In that case you could absolutely position the `double_line` at 50% from the top.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a backgruund image very easy.

If you are ok with using background images.

HTML:

```
<h2><span>Ce facem</span></h2>
```

CSS:

```
h2 { 
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/7LGlQ0I.png) repeat-x 0 center; 
    text-align: center;
}
h2 span { padding: 0 20px; background-color: #fff; }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Qu849/3/)

Or if you really prefer usin bordered element:

Then with a little tweaks in the css:

```
 .content_item>div{
    border-top: 2px solid #c2c1c1;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #a5a4a4;
    width:100%;
    height:5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    }
.content_item>h2{
        display: inline;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0 10px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
.content_item{
    text-align: center;
     position:relative;   
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Qu849/6/)

Comment: Just seen your answer, That's what i said anyway (after you, I was writing :P) but you used an example so +1 for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Rodik is right

Try using:

```
.content_item>h2 {
text-align: center;
display: block;
width: 200px;
background-color: #ffffff;
margin-top: -20px;
margin-left: 30%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give `position:absolute;` and `margin` to your `<h2>`

Replace your `<h2>` style with this:

```
.content_item>h2{
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #ffffff;
    position:absolute;
    margin:-10px 41% 0px;
    }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qu849/7/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 .content_item>div{
   border-top: 2px solid #c2c1c1;
border-bottom: 2px solid #a5a4a4;
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
height: 5px;
position: relative;
    }
.content_item>h2{
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
width: 200px;
z-index: 12;
position: absolute;
top: -23px;
text-align: center;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: 20px auto;
    }
.content_item{
 position:relative;   
}
}
```

use this code usefull for you.
see this link http://jsfiddle.net/bipin_kumar/35T7S/1/

Answer (score 0):

if in doubt, you could just make the text an image with full transparent background, this makes it easier when it comes to responsive webpage layouts (different resolutions etc.)

Answer (score 0):

**Pure Css with No images**

Ammend this in your CSS to check if it helps :

```
.content_item>h2{
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        display:inline-block;  // makes header size equal to text width
        width : 30%;   //gives indented left-right white-space
        position:absolute; //to overlay it on double-line
        top : 0px; //position
        display: table;  //centre inline elements
        margin : 0 auto;
        margin-left : 40% //hack to center it
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, another way

```
        .content_item>div{
border-top: 2px solid #c2c1c1;
border-bottom: 2px solid #a5a4a4;
display:inline-block;
width:100%;
height:5px;
position: relative;
}

 .content_item>h2{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:-30px;
    margin-left:50%;
   }
```

When z-index not used this type of issue, use above format.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it:

```css
.content_item {
    position:relative;
}
.content_item > div {
    border-top: 2px solid #c2c1c1;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #a5a4a4;
    XXdisplay:inline-block; /* not needed */
    width:100%;
    height:5px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -3px;
}
.content_item > h2 {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 200px; /* must be specified */
    margin: 0 auto; /* for centering */
}
```

To the `.double-line` div, add `z-index: -1` to force it to be painted under the `h2` element.
Use `top: 50%` and a negative `margin-top: -3px` to vertically align the double lines (if that is what you need).

You then need to specified a width for `h2` other wise it will be 100% wide and the white background will paint over the dobule-lines.  Add `margin: 0 auto` to center the `h2` within the parent container.

You do not need `display: inline-block` for the `.double-line` since the absolute positioning will force the display type to be `block`.

Demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/nB2a3/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without absolute positioning and without changing the HTML.

Rather than having the `text-align: center` on the `<h2>`, you can set it on the `.content-item`.  Then use `display: inline-block` on the `<h2>` and relatively position it with a negative top value.

Like so:

```
.content_item>div {
  border-top: 2px solid #c2c1c1;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #a5a4a4;
  width:100%;
  height:5px;
}
.content_item>h2 {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 40px;
  position: relative;
  top: -15px;
}
.content_item {
  text-align: center; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Qu849/11/